# Safety in laravel file upload

Tags: laravel, file, upload

I have a simple question.. Is it safe to have a app that has a file upload system for users to send images to our project, and store those files in this directory?

```
$file->move(public_path('../storage/app/public/files'), $name);
```

Or is it better to store in:

```
$file->move(public_path('files'), $name);
```

This way it stores the file in the "files" directory inside the public directory.

Answer (score 0):

That would be ok and also depends on your app and number of users but I recommend to change the name of the file and also you can accept only JPG or PNG file for more security for changing the name of the file you can do it like this :

```
   $image_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('images'), $image_name);
```

Comment: Yes, i already change the name of the file, and already only accept jpg and png.. My question was just about the security of the folders. But thank you for your answer!! You've answered and addeed more info, so thanks!

Comment: Since you've already answered me once, do you know whats the best way to retrieve the image, when the file had the name changed? should i keep the old name in the database table or ir there another way to do it ?

Comment: now you are working locally but in a real app you show put it in a specific path on the server so for now it is ok to save it on the public folder and you have full access to all file in the app

Answer (score 0):

with this function you can get all data from db for that id then you can show whatever you want in the blade

```
public function show($id)
{
    $data = YOUR_MODEL::findOrFail($id);
    return view('view', compact('data'));

}
```